# how to change a point color, style or size in line chart using achartengine android

Tags: achartengine, linechart

I'm developing an app now with achartengine to draw a line chart. Now I have a problem with an effect that I hope to fix. The effect is, when users touch a point on the line chart the color or style of point can be changed to different color or style. But the other points should remain the same as before.

I was not able to find any function to set a point color or style on achartengine API document.

Can someone please point me to any documentation that can help me with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such API available. However, you could create a temporary series that would contain one single point (the selected one), add it only as long as you need it and when no longer needed, just remove it from the dataset.